# How can I access Low Variables I've used on a previous site without having to input them all in again?

Tags: low-variables

I want to use a common set of Low Variables I've used on another EE build but don't want to have to go through the configuration again. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low Variables are stored in the exp_low_variables , exp_low_variable_groups and exp_global_variables tables.

You can dump these tables from your previous build into your new project.

Note that it won't work for complex Low Variable types that store their data in their own database tables, like Matrix/Grid.